# Using Emacs to send Tweets or Queets

Tags: web

I'm using [Quitter](https://quitter.se/qbi) or [Twitter](https://twitter.com/qbi/) to send out short messages. Most of my Queets/Tweets go out through the web interface. However I'd like to use Emacs for it. Does anyone a good method/mode to use with Quitter or Twitter?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [EmacsWiki's page on Twitter](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Twitter) for suggestions.  Personally, I've had good luck with [Twittering Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TwitteringMode).

- [`twittering-mode`](https://github.com/hayamiz/twittering-mode) on GitHub

  - Use `M-x twit` as an entry point. It will handle authorization as part of its process.
  - `i` to display profile pictures
  - `j`/`k` next/previous tweet
  - `u` tweet
  - …
  - `M-x twittering-update-status-from-minibuffer` (not `(interactive)` by default; recommend using an interactive wrapper function and binding to a key)

Comment: Link-only answers should be avoided on stackexchange sites, because they could become void should the links die. Also (personal opinion ahead), I find that the emacswiki is pretty much broken by design, and redirecting users there is not really helping anybody.